# Form Field Layout issue with Accordion

Tags: html, css, forms, layout

I have a form and I'm using CSS to layout the fields on the screen.
This is working as I'd like and can be seen here :
**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/b6f3p9at/)**

I'm now trying to apply the same layout to a form within a CSS Accordion layout and it's getting messed up. This **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u7q3gwbs/4/)**  shows what going wrong.

This is the HTML I'm using :

```
<div class='block'><label>&nbsp;Text 1</label><input type="text" name="text1" /></div>

<div class='block'><label>&nbsp;Text 2</label><input type="text" name="text2" /></div>
```

and the CSS:

```
div.block {overflow:hidden; }
div.block label {width:325px; display:block; float:left; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; }
```

I'm assuming this is messing up as accordion is using the `<lable>` tag to create the sections.. and I'm using it to layout the fields.

So how do I layout my form fields neatly and keep the accordion working ?

This is the final result I'm after:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: that is lots of code in the 2nd demo, can you attach a desired output as an image?

Comment: Image showing final layout added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your form styles are being overridden by the accordion's CSS. Neither have very impressive specificity. You can fix this particular problem by moving your CSS to the end and adding an ancestor selector to increase rank:

```
.horizontal div.block {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.horizontal div.block label {
    width:325px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/u7q3gwbs/5/)**

**[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/u7q3gwbs/7)** to remove border & background from interior labels.

I haven't added all necessary reset styles on your elements. A better approach might be to add classes to the outer labels, and modify the accordion CSS to target that class, or use a child selector (`.horizontal > ul > li > label`). That would prevent you from needing to reset so many properties.

A best-practice approach for situations like this is to load a third-party product like this in its own CSS file, along with any others in their respective files, and then load your custom CSS file that includes any overrides. This makes it easier to get your styles to trump the others, which is normally what you'd want.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="accordion.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="widget.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" />
```

Comment: Image added to original post to show what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Thanks - the updated layout doesn't seem to look like the image I posted. I get a big input field that changes color when you hover over it. ?

Comment: See my updated answer. I won't have time to work out all the details for you. This provides the necessary direction, though.

Comment: @Rocket isherwood has pointed out the right direction, I think you can complete the rest, but let us know if you still have trouble with it.

Comment: Thanks that has helped.